# Как сделать авто скрол с offset для RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня есть горизонтальный `RecyclerView` который автоматически листает контент раз в 3 секунды

Сделал как описано тут

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773980/recyclerview-auto-scroll-to-display-all-the-elements-as-in-news-feed-etc

все отлично работало до тех пор пока ширина ячейки была на всю шинину экрана.

Теперь мне нужно сделать, чтоб ячейка была меньше по размеру чем ширина экрана и у меня получилось так

[image]

Не красиво выглядит потому, что ячейка не посередине

Мне нужно чтоб ячейка при автоматическом свайпе останавливалась не доезжая до конца. Чтоб было вот так

[image]

Конец предыдущей - центральная - следующая ячейки

Получается, что в методе который описан по ссылке выше

```
@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position)
{
    LinearSmoothScroller linearSmoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext())
    {
        @Override
        public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition)
        {
            return SmoothLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
        }

        @Override
        protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics)
        {
            return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
        }
    };

    linearSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller);
}
```

я могу контролировать скорость анимации свайпа, но я не могу задать offset

Есть еще один метод

```
scrollToPositionWithOffset(final int position, final int offset)
```

И он может сделать нужный мне offset , но он не делает анимацию свайпа

Как анимацию с первого метода применить с offset параметром со второго метода

Любые идеи говорите

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39654328 - а так пробовали?

Comment: @woesss да, это то, что мне нужно. Опубликуйте этот ответ и я отмечу как правильный. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я указал в своем ответе здесь

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964701/how-to-make-auto-smooth-scroll-with-offset-recycler-view/53036053?noredirect=1#comment93059650_53036053

Опубликую, что у меня вышло так же как ответ к этому вопросу

Спасибо @woesss за ссылку на этот ответ

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39654328

В итоге получилось вот так

Мой кастомный `LinnearLayoutManager`

```
public class SmoothLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager
{
public static final int X_25 = 25;
public static final int X_200 = 200;
public static final float DEFAULT = X_25;

/**
 * !! IMPORTANT !!
 * If you need to add new value, don't forget add it here also
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@IntDef({X_25, X_200})
private @interface Speed
{

}

private static float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = DEFAULT;

public SmoothLayoutManager(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public SmoothLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)
{
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

public SmoothLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

public SmoothLayoutManager setSpeedOfSmooth(@Speed int iSpeed)
{
    MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = iSpeed;

    return this;
}

@Override
public void scrollToPositionWithOffset(final int position, final int offset)
{
    super.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset);
}

@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position)
{
    RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext())
    {
        @Override
        public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition)
        {
            return SmoothLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
        }

        @Override
        protected int getVerticalSnapPreference()
        {
            return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_ANY;
        }

        @Override
        protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics)
        {
            return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
        }

        @Override
        public int calculateDtToFit(final int viewStart, final int viewEnd, final int boxStart, final int boxEnd, final int snapPreference)
        {
            return (boxStart + (boxEnd - boxStart) / 2) - (viewStart + (viewEnd - viewStart) / 2);
        }
    };

    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
}
}
```

И применяеться это вот таким образом

```
private void setRv(Context iC)
    {
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new UpSaleInnerAdapter(mPicasso, mInflater, iLink -> mListener.onButtonClick(iLink));

        mRv.setLayoutManager(new SmoothLayoutManager(iC, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false).setSpeedOfSmooth(SmoothLayoutManager.X_200));
        mRv.setAdapter(adapter);

        SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRv);
    }
```

> Примечание :
>
> Я заметил, что если быстро свайпнуть пальцем по экрану, то это путает `SnapHelper` и он как бы скролит дальше чем нужно. Скажем я делаю свайп офидаю , что где то 10 ячеек проскролиться и я увижу контент, но на самом деле скрол продолжается еще + на 10 ячеек. И  этот `турбо режим`  становиться заметным.
>
> Если кто то с этим сталкивался и знает о чем речь, подскажите можно ли это исправить
>
> Спасибо!